# vim frequently does not display text

Tags: vim, gvim

My vim frequently does not display (some) text in terminal. It just shows blank area. If I attempt to select (either through mouse or keyboard), the text would appear.

The issue is more severe in terminal (I use xterm on Fluxbox), not so much (but still occurs) on gvim.

does anybody know how to solve such problem?

Comment: Possibly a video driver issue?

Comment: Syntax highlighting?

Comment: a screenshot would help